# ffmpeg - No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, видео, ffmpeg

Ничего понять не могу, поставил ffmpeg Ubuntu (ffmpeg version n4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1))

пытаюсь сделать:

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/public_html/beyond/ffmpeg/test.mp4
```

ошибка:

> No such file or directory

делаю так прямо из директории

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4
```

> No such file or directory

Ок делаю так:

```
stat /var/www/public_html/beyond/ffmpeg/test.mp4
```

все отлично работает, никто не сталкивался с этим, ничего не понимаю. Если запускаю с параметром **-v error** выдает инфу:

> unable to open display и No such file or directory.

Comment: попробуйте `sudo` перед командой

Comment: нет к сожалению никакого эффекта, пробовал даже так /snap/bin/ffmpeg вместо просто ffmpeg такой же эффект

Comment: странно на SUSE версия 3.4.4 работает на ура, попробую установить версию новее, или старее

Comment: а что насчёт прав файла? может элементарно нет прав на чтение?

Comment: проставил chmod 777, Доступ: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (65534/  nobody)   Gid: (65534/ nogroup)

Comment: в SUSE тот же файл - 0644

Comment: анука с рабочего стола просто файл потелебонькать попробую)

Comment: так понял проблема в nobody ))) погружусь в основы прав и групп linux сегодня)

Comment: скорее всего, он не может подключиться к дисплею, и нет опции куда отправлять выхлоп

Comment: эта особенность ffmpeg он работает только с директорией /home, выставлял права и настройки в snap бесполезно, упорно работает только с /home ;(